# C# Convert.ChangeType() throw InvalidCastException on conversion between int and object

Tags: c#, .net, exception, type-conversion

I have a problem with with the ChangeType() method, it used to work fine but now throws: `Object must implement IConvertible.`

The code used to be like this:

```
Type type = DataType.TypeDictionary[(DataType.TYPE)setting.SettingType];

object value = binFormer.Deserialize(memStream);

Settings.Add(setting.SettingName, Convert.ChangeType(value, type));
```

Now is like that:

```
Type type = DataType.TypeDictionary[(DataType.TYPE)setting.SettingType];

object value = binFormer.Deserialize(memStream);

settingItem.SettingName = setting.SettingName;
settingItem.SettingComment = setting.SettingComment;
settingItem.SettingData = Convert.ChangeType(value, type);

Settings.Add(settingItem);
```

The data on which it throws exception is type - Int32 and the value should be object. I did not change the convert itself...I am probably missing something obvious.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The message is quite clear - `value` is of a type that doesn't implement `IConvertible`. Use the debugger to find out the actual type of the value, for example.

Comment: You are right, the problem was actually elsewhere as other function output changed, thanks you for the answer.